# Algebra Problem #1

Tags: factoring

How can this be solved in a simple way?

> Find all positive integer pairs $(a,b)$ such that
>   $$a^3 - b^3 - 6b^2 + 6a^2 = 1863$$

I'm not exactly sure how this can be solved simply. I've tried factoring, but I can't get much farther.

Comment: What do you mean by 'solved'? Do you want to factorize the expression? Or are you looking to find values for $a$ and $b$?

Comment: I am looking to find possible integer pairs (a,b). sorry for not clarifying in the original post!!

Comment: Unless you have a second equation, you are looking at infinite possible integer pairs $(a, b)$ which you can only find by trial-and-error.

Comment: @an4s This is not necessarily a trial and error problem. Diophantine equations are a robust field of study.

Comment: @Valborg You are right. The OP needs to clarify the question further.

Comment: I changed it slightly. It's supposed to be all positive integer pairs. Does that help? Because I was told there was only 1 solution

Answer (score 3):

So you are interested in solving the following Diophantine equation in the positive integers:
$$
a^3 - b^3 + 6(a^2 - b^2) = (a-b)\left[a^2+ab+b^2+6a+6b\right] = 1863
$$
If $a=b$, then there are no solutions.

If $a>b> 0$, then there are only finitely many cases to check, since the following holds when $b\geq 25$: 
$$
\left|(a-b)\left[a^2+ab+b^2+6a+6b\right]\right|>3b^2>1863
$$

If $b>a>0$, then there are only finitely many cases to check since the following holds when $a\geq 25$: 
$$
\left|(a-b)\left[a^2+ab+b^2+6a+6b\right]\right|>3a^2>1863
$$
I have just completed the script to exhaust over these possibilities, and it would appear that the only solution is $(a,b)=(14,11)$.

Comment: Is there a faster/easier way to solve it? I feel like checking cases takes a lot of time.

Comment: @user546105 Unfortunately many Diophantine equations will have some level of case checking involved with finding all solutions. Is that the case here? I honestly do not know. I would be mildly surprised if there was a substantially better way of showing there is only one solution in the positive integers to this equation. Really messy and awkward things happen when you are dealing with small integers, so there are usually strange cases that simply have to be tracked down by hand, and not handled with a more general and powerful theory.

Comment: @user546105 Now what you might be able to do quite easily is come up with better estimates than I have here; I really did not try at all to make the bounds on $a$ and $b$ nice, nor did I think hard about my cases. It could be that you can significantly reduce the computation involved, but pretty much any computer and most graphing calculators can solve this problem over the ranges I gave in less than 60 seconds.

Comment: @user546105 In case you have not seen it, there is a better answer posed here with significantly fewer cases to consider, all of which can be done by hand.

Answer (score 2):

As Valborg wrote,
$a^3 - b^3 + 6(a^2 - b^2) 
= (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2+6a+6b) 
= 1863
=9\cdot 207
=81\cdot 23
=3^4\cdot 23
$.

Let
$a-b = c$,
so
$a = b+c$.
Then
$a^2+ab+b^2+6a+6b
=(b+c)^2+(b+c)b+b^2+6(b+c)+6b
=3 b^2 + 3 b c + 12 b + c^2 + 6 c
$
so
$c(3 b^2 + 3 b c + 12 b + c^2 + 6 c)
=3^4 23
$.

If
$3 \not\mid c$
then
$3 \not \mid (3 b^2 + 3 b c + 12 b + c^2 + 6 c)
$
which can;t be.
So,
let $c = 3d$,

Then
$3^4 23
=3d(3 b^2 + 9 b d + 12 b + 9d^2 + 18 d)
=9d( b^2 + 3 b d + 4 b + 3d^2 + 6 d)
$
so
$3^2 23
=207
=d( b^2 + 3 b d + 4 b + 3d^2 + 6 d)
=d((b+d)^2 +  b d + 4 b + 2d^2 + 6 d)
$.

If
$23 | d$,
the right side is too big.
Therefore
$d = 1, 3,$ or $9$.

If
$d=1$ then
$207
= b^2 + 3 b  + 4 b + 3 + 6 
=b^2+7b+9
$
so
$b=-18, 11$.
So $b=11,
c=3,
a=14
$.

If
$d=3$
then
$69
= b^2 + 9 b  + 4 b + 27 +  18
= b^2 + 13 b  +45
$
which has no integer roots.

If
$d = 9$
then
$23
= b^2 + 27 b  + 4 b + 243 + 54
= b^2 + 31 b  + 297
$
which has no integer roots.

Therefore
$a=14, b=11$
is the only solution.

Comment: Very nice, much better than solving 50 cubic polynomials. And with the added benefit of detecting the negative integer solution as well.

Comment: Upvoting would be nice, then.

Comment: Just for you I bothered to finish registering. Enjoy the upvote, lol.

Comment: Thank you. Upvoted your comment:)

Answer (score 1):

Noodling around

$a^3 - b^3 - 6b^2 + 6a^2 = 1863$

$a^3 + 6a^2 + 12a + 8 -b^3-6b^2 -12b - 8 = 1863 +12(a-b)$

$(a + 2)^3 - (b + 2)^3 = 1863 + 12(a-b)$

$(a - b)((a+2)^2 + (a+2)(b+2) + (b+2)^2 = 1863 + 12(a-b)$

Assuming $a \ne b$ (in which case $0=1863$ so we know that cant be) then

$(a + 2)^2  +(a+2)(b+2) + (b+2)^2 = \frac {1863}{a-b} + 12$

So $a-b|1863 = 3^4*23$

As $a$ and $b$ are both positive, we know that $a > b$

Let $a = b + k$ and so

$(a +2)^2 + (a+2)(a +2 - k) + (a+ 2 - k)^2 = \frac {1863}{k} + 12$

Which can be solved by the quadratic formula.

$(a^2 + 4a + 4) + (a^2 + 4a + 4) - (a+2)k + (a^2 + 4a + 4) -2k(a+2) + k^2 =\frac {1863}{k} + 12$